# How do I convert string cell value of a number into a number increment by 1?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to fetch the last row's row id (located in the first column) to increment it by one once there is a new row added. However I am not sure on how to convert the string into a number to increment by 1

What I tried:

```
  var url = "";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");

  var rowID = ws.getRange(ws.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().toString().parseInt()+1; 
  console.log(rowID);
```

Which is not a function based on the log.

Comment: About `I am trying to fetch the last row's row id (located in the first column) to increment it by one once there is a new row added.`, can you provide the sample values of your `string cell value` of `string cell value of a number into a number increment by 1`? For example, the values are `1`, `2`, `3`,,,?

Comment: The value is 3 but when I try var rowID = ws.getRange(ws.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().toString()+1; the output/result will be "31" and not 4.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. I think that the reason for `31` is due to that `3` and `1` are merged as a string value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values of your `id` is `1`, `2`, `3`,,, , how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var rowID = ws.getRange(ws.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().toString().parseInt()+1;
```

#### To:

```
var rowID = (parseInt(ws.getRange(ws.getLastRow(), 1).getValue(), 10) || 0) + 1;
```

or

```
var rowID = (Number(ws.getRange(ws.getLastRow(), 1).getValue()) || 0) + 1;
```

or, in the event the value in the last row is known to always be a number or a blank, the following modification might be able to be used.

```
var rowID = ws.getRange(ws.getLastRow(), 1).getValue() + 1;
```

#### Reference:

- [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)